# Batch Insert using hibernate with dependent auto generated ids

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a large set od data say(7000) of data that needs to to *inserted* in three tables 
say table **A,B,C** and all having an autogenerated column **@id**.

Now Table **B** is dependent on **A**'s auto generated **@id** .

During batch insert I want to
set a logic so that after a certain threshold the records will be persistent/commit
to the database and I am using **hibernate transaction**.
Is it possible to get the dependent auto generated id from **A**'s table before it 
is been persisted /commit.

Thanks for the reply in advance

Answer (score 2):

Auto-generated IDs in databases that do not support explicit sequences (such as MySQL) are retrieved upon insertion. There is no other mechanism for it, unless you simulate the generation on the Java side and set them there. That, however will not work well if your application ever runs with more than one instance.